# Looking to write a code in Java to get details of ALL of the Items of an Array (varying length of inputs)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, string-formatting

```
//Class Item
public class Item {

}

String A, B; 
    int C, D;

// Constructor


public Item(String A, String B, int C, int D) {

this.A = A;

this.B = B

this.C = C;

this.D = D

public String toFormattedString() {

        return String.format("%s %s %d %d", A, B, C, D);    

//Class ItemTest

public class ItemTest {

    Rocket itemList [];


public ItemTest() {

      itemList = new Item[5];
      doSampleItem();

itemList[0] = new Item("A”, "ABC DEF", 400, 35);

itemList[1] = new Item("aaaa”, "bbbbbbbbbb", 10, 1000);

itemList[2] = new Item("ccc ddddd”, "eeeee ffff jjjj", 66000, 888);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a way to retrieve the values of the `Rocket itemList []` of the `ItemTest` class, you can write a getter for `Rocket itemList []` in the `ItemTest` class as below,

```
public Rocket getItemList() {
    return this.itemList;
}
```

Comment: I have to display a formatted output of the array. If you see, it takes any variable length of inputs. So I am confused about how to make it work. I have used normal For Loop and System.out.print but that is not formatting the output for varying length of the input string

Comment: I missed adding this requirement in the main question. Not sure how to edit this in my main Quer :( I am new